# Android : SurfaceView in not working in my Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, surfaceview

I have instantiated a SurfaceView and attached to an activity using `setContentView(surface);` . When I am running it on real devices working fine, but in Android emulator it was showing only white screen. Also I have tested in different systems, some systems working fine and  some are not.

All systems are Ubuntu 16.04, emulators running on same configuration, API level 26. I can say all systems has same development environment.

Please help me to find out what would be the cause behind it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the hardware GLES render is responsible for this issue.

You can force software rendering in the AVD device configuration which fixes the issue:
[image: Virtual Device Configuration]